# I get a different C# object instance when calling the constructor from reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Compare the two instances of the same class below. The variable `instanceA` is created using reflection, while `instanceB` is created using a direct reference to the DLL from my VS2012 project.

```
var a = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\MyFilePath.dll"));
var t = a.GetType("Namespace.MyClassType");

var instanceA = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
var instanceB = new Namespace.MyClassType();
```

The problem? ***These are not equal***. The fields in `instanceA` and `instanceB` are different. Currently my code is working, as long as I'm using `instanceB`. But if I change only the letter "B" to "A" then the resulting object is somewhat different which in a later stage breaks the product.

As you probably understand, my task is to use reflection instead of a reference. I have confirmed that the correct constructor is being called.

Comment: Please specify "different".

Comment: How do you know they are "different"?

Comment: In particular, they shouldn't be equal because they will have different reference addresses.

Comment: You're referencing two different assemblies, most likely.  You're loading one version and the application is bound to another version.

Comment: A property in `instanceA` is null, which is not in `instanceB`

Comment: Why do you think they have to be equals?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria Doesn't matter - I want them to be!

Comment: what sort of property is it ? a `static` one perhaps?

Comment: @Simeon: They're both calling the same parameterless constructor - does that constructor actually set the property? If so, how? There's all kinds of information you should be providing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've got different assemblies - in one case you've loaded an assembly just from a byte array (which *happened* to be stored on disk as `MyFilePath.dll`) and in the other you're referring to the assembly which was loaded into the AppDomain due to the references in your project.

It's not really clear *exactly* what your context is (where the different assemblies are, etc) but you should look into how you're loading assemblies - that's the crux of it, rather than the `Activator.CreateInstance` part.

Comment: Half-constructive... how do I fix it?

Comment: @Simeon: Stop doing that?

Comment: OK so how do I simulate the context of referencing the DLL? As opposed to loading the same DLL as a `byte[]`? Do you need to know my exact context in order to respond on how to create the context?

Comment: I solved this! By using **`Assembly.LoadFrom`** (instead of `Load`)

Comment: Accepting this answer, as it contained hints in "AppDomain", "how you're loading assemblies" etc. and a lack of competing answers